# PC processor limited to 66%

Tags: windows-10, cpu, cpu-usage

My Windows computer, when I put a lot of strain on it and open task management, always shows me that the [processor is 66%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgP0S.png) used and never more. This limits me a lot in using the computer, because it is much slower.

I would like the processor to be able to be used 100 per cent.

Anyway, here is the processor: Intel Core Duo E8400 3.00Ghz

I have searched the Internet many times about this problem but have found nothing. It seems as if there is a limiter on the processor that would have a power of 3.00Ghz, but only uses 1.98Ghz.

With another app (OCCT) this problem seemed to occur: the performance graph was up to 100%.

Comment: What power mode is your system configured to?

Comment: Have you checked your CPU temperature? CPU will limit its clock frequency to protect itself from overheated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you put "a lot of strain" on your CPU?

Did you use this free software, portable, free, for example:

https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/powermax.html

I can't believe the fact it doesn't show 100% *"limits me a lot in using the computer"*, very sorry.

**What's limiting is more probably:**

- a discontinued old processor with only 2 cores,
- an old socket which means an old motherboard, and the associated DDR**2** DRAM,
- a probably obsolete drive which I guess is an HDD (*see edit),
- old ports like USB 2.00, and I imagine the video, etc.

That could be the problems that limits you.

**Edit**: I just saw in the screen copy you provided you have an SSD; that's very fine. Congratulations. But the amount of DRAM (DDR2) is very low **7**GB and a bit bizarre, maybe 4+2+1 GB in 3 modules? If you could find 2 **identical** DRAM modules of 4 GB that you'd put in slots 1 and 3, it may help - a bit.

Anyway, the CPU isn't the problem here, it's the whole PC.

Comment: I first changed the RAM, but the problem persisted, so I tried removing the wifi card and the video card, but the processor kept running at a maximum of 66%.
In the end I changed the motherboard to a slightly newer one (Asus H87M-E) with 10Gb of DDR3 RAM (2+2+2+4).
Now everything works properly and the computer is much faster.
I think the problem was in the processor which I have now changed to an Intel Core i3 4160 3.60GHz